Using Maestro API with C# nuget package getting 404 error from DocuSign
I’m trying to use Maestro API from DocuSign using the C# nuget package and I keep getting 404 error, I confirmed I am using using a valid access token, I can use this access token with the regular eSign SDK which I used before, but for this new I keep getting 404 error for some reason.
The code I'm running is this:
var maestroApi = new WorkflowTriggerApi(docuSignClient);
var payload = new TriggerPayload
{
    InstanceName = model.InstanceName,
    Metadata = new object(),
    Participants = new object(),
    Payload = new
    {
        signerEmail = model.SignerEmail,
        signerName = model.SignerName,
        ccEmail = model.CCEmail,
        ccName = model.CCName,
    },
};

var uriParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(triggerUrl.Query);
var options = new WorkflowTriggerApi.TriggerWorkflowOptions
{
    mtid = uriParameters["mtid"],
    mtsec = uriParameters["mtsec"],
};
return maestroApi.TriggerWorkflow(accountId, payload, options);

I went over the documentation that I found on https://developers.docusign.com/docs/maestro-api/how-to/trigger-workflow/ and followed the code that was in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Maestro/Examples/TriggerWorkflowService.cs

The new Maestro API is still in beta, but it’s fully functional and you should be able to use it using the C# Maestro SDK. All developer accounts now have access to Maestro, so there’s no reason it won’t happen to you. The issue is most likely that you forgot to add the new scope which is required for authentication for this API. When you request an access token, please add aow_manage to the list of scopes similar to how you had signature when you used the eSignature REST API int the past.
